# How to set range of values on BarLegend and Manipulate Polygons color filling using BarLegend

Tags: graphics, manipulate, legending

I have a simple graphics which display a polygon and a bar legend.
I am having difficulties defining a range of values for my bar legend.
What I am looking to get is 4 values: 10^-10, 10^-6, 10^-3, 10^-1 (Green>Amber>Red);

Ultimately I would like to control my polygons color filling using bar legend as a controller. 
Here is what I have at present:

```
    Manipulate[
 Row[
  {BarLegend[{{Green, Yellow, Red}, {10^-10, 10^-1}}, 
    LegendLayout -> "Column"], 
   Graphics[
    Polygon[{{-1, 1}, {0, -1}, {1, 1}}, 
     VertexColors -> {Red, Green, Red}], PlotRange -> 1, 
    ImageSize -> {220, 220}]
   }
  ]
 , {{x, .0, "Level:"}, 0, 1, .1, ImageSize -> Medium}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Bottom] (*Controller for filling goes here *)
```

I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me out to figure out how to set the appropriate range for my BarLegend and perhaps to give me some pointers on how could I achieve filling my Polygon using BarLegend as a control or some similar structure.

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

As Mr Wizard observed my original code is not self contained. For reasons that I fail to understand this seemed to work with what seemed a fresh session. The code works if you move the  gauge marker but to post correct code (I leave the animated gif as it is the same outcome):

```
DynamicModule[{s = 0},
 Framed[Row[{VerticalGauge[Dynamic[s], {0, 1}, 
     ScaleRanges -> Partition[Range[0, 1, 0.05], 2, 1], 
     ScaleRangeStyle -> cf], 
    Dynamic@Graphics[
      Polygon[{{-1, 1}, {0, -1}, {1, 1}}, 
       VertexColors -> {Red, cf[s], Red}], PlotRange -> 1, 
      ImageSize -> {220, 220}]}]], 
 Initialization -> (cf[z_] := Blend[{Green, Yellow, Red}, z])]
```

[image]

Here is my fresh session:

[image]

**Desired scale**
The linear gauges are linear scales. The best I could do (without creating a separate gauge) is the following. Note the it appears `ScaleRangeFunction` uses {0,1}  whereas grahic required rescaling.

```
DynamicModule[{s = -10},
 Framed[Row[{VerticalGauge[Dynamic[s], {-10, -1}, 
     GaugeLabels -> "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(x\)]\)", 
     LabelStyle -> 12, 
     ScaleRanges -> Partition[Range[-10, -1, 1], 2, 1], 
     ScaleDivisions -> {10, 2}, ScaleRangeStyle -> cf], 
    Dynamic@Graphics[
      Polygon[{{-1, 1}, {0, -1}, {1, 1}}, 
       VertexColors -> {Red, cf[Rescale[s, {-10, -1}, {0, 1}]], Red}],
       PlotRange -> 1, ImageSize -> {220, 220}]}]], 
 Initialization -> (cf[z_] := Blend[{Green, Yellow, Red}, z])]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much it looks amazing! I was wondering if you could help me with the labels. How would I adjust labels of the barlegend to go from 1x10^-10 to 1x10^-6 then 1x10^3 and finally to 1x10^-1?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard hello, I am not sure - but it works! I am a bit of a beginner in Mathematica.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It is self contained. It seems to be one of the nice features of the gauges...I have played with other gauges for other purposes and exploited this...otherwise I cannot comment.

Comment: @ubpdqn how could I adjust the labels in bar legend to values I have mentioned above? :s Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it did not throw an error on fresh session cut and pasted on windows 8 version 10 on my machine. I am most likely to be wrong but am in full work day in the antipodes...will look at in 8 hours

Comment: @namelessicecream apologies for delay...will look at when get chance...time zone issues

Comment: @Mr.Wizard feeling rather stupid...have posted what I hope now makes sense...suspect that despite fresh run on my machine had cursor on gauge marker masking error (was 1 am when i checked)...if wrong again will amend

Comment: @namelessicecream  sorry best I can do with edit

Comment: Problem corrected in edit. +1

Comment: @ubpdqn great answer! I am working on something similar. I was wondering if I could I ask for your email address to keep in touch with you in future?